# What do you call a variable that has a getter and setter defined, with no backing variable?

Tags: oop, terminology

What is it called when you define a variable/property with a getter *and setter*, such that the language does not automatically generate a backing variable?

E.g. in Swift, we could define a `modalViewController` property that doesn't create a backing variable:

```
extension MyViewController {
    var modalViewController: UIViewController? {
        get { return self.presentedViewController }
        set { self.present(newValue, animated: true) }
    }
}
```

What's the proper term to describe the `modalViewController` property?

---

I know that if it's only gettable, it would be called a **computed property**:

```
extension Int {
    var isEven: Bool { 
        get { return self % 2 == 0 }
    }
}
```

However, I'm looking for a term for something that is **both settable and gettable**.

---

The reason I'm looking for a term is that I want to ask a question related to these types of properties, and would like to use common, non-ambiguous language. I thought this would be called a *virtual property*, but it doesn't appear to be the proper name as [virtual has a different meaning in OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).

Answer (score 1):

Even though they have a setter too, Swift (at least) [calls these **"computed properties"**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) (emphasis added):

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and enumerations can define **computed properties**, which do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter **and an optional setter** to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.