# How to bind a picker to a computed value SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, userdefaults

I have a view SettingsView written using swiftui, and a data store SettingsStore that uses UserDefaults as the underlying data storage.

```
final class SettingsStore: ObservableObject {
    
    var velocityLocation: RenderLocation {
        set { defaults.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: Keys.velocityLoaction) }
        get { RenderLocation(rawValue: defaults.integer(forKey: Keys.velocityLoaction)) ?? .top }
    }
}
```

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @State var settings: SettingsStore = SettingsStore();
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Render settings")) {
                Toggle("Render velocity to video", isOn: $settings.renderVelocityToVideo)
                
                Picker(selection: $settings.velocityLocation, label: Text("Render location")) {
                    ForEach(RenderLocation.allCases) { b in
                        Text(b.name).tag(b)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

When I pick a new value in the picker it is persisted to user defaults correctly, but it is not rendered to the view. This is because the get for the computed property is never called. If I leave that view and come back the picker now has the correct value.

I know my use of an Enum in the picker works as when I change the computed property in SettingsStore, to a simple @State property in the view everything works as expected (except of course saving to UserDefaults)

Is there a way to get computed property to render after being set or is there a better way to structure this code so that i can persist picker values easily.

(Yes I have tried this with other data types eg ints, string same issue)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59341588/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi 's solutions is right, but an alternative that might work depending on the rest of the app, is to use`@AppStorage` to handle the UserDefaults. It will handle View updates. Add an AppStorage variable for velocity (as an Int) directly in the View and add the computed var code to the View also. No need for an observable object to handle storage/retrieval of stuff.